# How to insert/place a movie clip from the library in a specific layer (z-order) in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I haven't found anything about this and it's really intriguing me. Here's an example:

```
var example1:example1_mc = new example1_mc();
addChild(example1);
```

It comes on top of all layers in my scene and I wanted to assign it to the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put an item at the back most z-index of it's parent, do the following:

```
addChildAt(example1,0);  

//the second parameter is the z-index to put the child at
//0 is the back, parent.numChildren-1 is the front most

//so this:
addChild(example1);

//is the same as this:
addChildAt(example1, numChildren-1);
```

`addChild` always places the child at the front.

To change the position of an item later, you can either `addChild/addChildAt` again, or use `setChildIndex(example1,0)`.

So this:

```
addChildAt(example1,0); //add it to the back
setChildIndex(example1,2); //move it above the next 2 items
```

is the exact* same as this:

```
addChildAt(example1,0);
addChildAt(example1,2); //since example1 is already added, this just moves it above the next 2 items in the parent (it doesn't add a copy)
```

*addChild will dispatch an `Event.ADDED` event on the item you added the child to. `setChildIndex` will not result in that event being dispatched.*